# Using LSET or RSET in a c#-aspx application

Tags: c#, string

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't seem to be able to use LSET and RSET string functions in a c# Code-Behind page.

My code is as follows :

```
    string ts = LSet(someString, 16);
```

Visual Web developper does not recognize LSet.

A co-worker is doing the same type of job in the same context except he uses VB for Code-Behind. I asked him to try

His code is as follows :

```
    Dim ts as String 
    ts = LSet(someString, 16)
```

This works perfectly.

So, I tried to add

```
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

in my c# page. LSet is still not recognized.

What did I do wrong ? Are LSet and RSet not usable in c# ? If so, why ?
I know PadLeft and PadRight are similar, but they don't cut the string if it's greater than the specified length, so I'd still like to use LSet and RSet.

Comment: They are usable, but you need to prepend the module they are in which in this case is `Strings`. So in other words; `Strings.LSet(someString, 16)`. Though you should probably use `Substring` instead (the C# way to do it).

Comment: Ok, that was obvious and i missed it :). It worked. `LSet(someString,10)` is a bit easier to write than `someString.PadRight(10).Substring(0,10)` but, above all, i wanted to understand what i did wrong. Thanks a lot for your quick answer.

Comment: Quick tips: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ it knows about these kinds of things (I didn't know it was in the `Strings` module, so I just entered `LSet(someString, 16)`, and it converted it to `Strings.LSet(someString, 16)` for me. For small examples like these where you just need to know what module something is in, tools like that are invaluable. For more complex code you should probably translate manually.

Comment: Also, if `LSet` set's the length of the string (I'm not a VB guy), you could simply do `str.PadRight(10 - str.Length)` (given that you know it's too long), or `str.Length >= 10 : str.Substring(10) : str.PadRight(10 - str.Length)`. At least for me, that would make it understandable what the code does ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Dim ts as String 
 ts = LSet(someString, 16)
```

can be done using [Strings.LSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.lset.aspx)

```
string ts="xxxx....";
var result = Strings.LSet(ts, 16)
```

Can achieve the same by using [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your project *References*, you need to add a reference to the *Microsoft.VisualBasic* assembly.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "123";
        var length = 6;
        var lSet = Strings.LSet(input, length);
        var rSet = Strings.RSet(input, length);

        // you could also have the same functionality 
        // without having to use LSet and RSet
        var padR = input.Substring(0, 
                Math.Min(input.Length, length))
            .PadRight(length, ' ');

        var padL = input.Substring(0, 
                Math.Min(input.Length, length))
            .PadLeft(length, ' ');

        Console.WriteLine(lSet == padR);
        Console.WriteLine(rSet == padL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the implementation

```
public static string LSet(string Source, int Length)
{
    if (Length == 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if (Source == null)
    {
        return new string(' ', Length);
    }
    if (Length > Source.Length)
    {
        return Source.PadRight(Length);
    }
    return Source.Substring(0, Length);
}
public static string RSet(string Source, int Length)
{
    if (Length == 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if (Source == null)
    {
        return new string(' ', Length);
    }
    if (Length > Source.Length)
    {
        return Source.PadLeft(Length);
    }
    return Source.Substring(0, Length);
}
```

or just add Microsoft.VisualBasic to references and use that namespace, you will find class called Strings it has those static members really all vb string methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pad or truncate semantics;

```
string ts = someString.PadRight(len).Substring(0, len);
```