# Moving Application from VB.NET Webforms to MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForms 4.0 application that I built as a sole developer. I started it in VB/Webforms because that is what I knew at the time.

I have now been doing C#/MVC and desperately want to switch the project over.

I know you can integrate MVC into Webforms (I've done that on another project). However, how can I move from VB to C#? I really don't want to start MVC in VB, so I feel the first thing I need to do is switch the project to VB.

If I want to move to C# slowly over time (part time development, as I add features), how can I go about doing that since it's an application and not a website? As far as I know, the application has to be all VB or C# unlike websites.

Comment: As far as I know you can have both .cs and .vb files in the same solution..

Comment: @retailcoder, you can in the same solution, but AFAIK, you can't in the same web application project.

Comment: No, but you can reference the c# dll from the vb dll and rewrite it in c# one bite at a time, replacing vb implementations by their rewritten c# equivalents.. that's how I'm tackling a VB6 to c# rewrite, while keeping the VB6 app in production.

Comment: @retailcoder, but would I be able to have C# aspx pages in a separate project and can you have two webform projects in the same solution?

Comment: Actually I think what I thought of woulnd't apply to web programming... sorry! +1 for the question though.

Comment: Webforms and MVC are two different technologies just concentrate on that and for vb to c# each part of vb can be converted to C# and there google will help a lot in that

Comment: I'm sure you don't need this a year later, but SharpDevelop has built-in tools that can convert an entire project from VB.NET to C#: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/articles/FeatureTourCodeConversion.aspx - I've used it to create a proof-of-concept conversion on a VB.NET project that's been around as long as ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an online translator for the two programming languages:

http://converter.telerik.com/

From my past experience it works pretty well.

Comment: Good suggestion, I just tried it. I don't know if I'd like all the code it produces, but something I could slowly tweak at least.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment .

Webforms and MVC are two different technologies just concentrate on that and for vb to c# each part of vb can be converted to C# and there google will help a lot in that

anything in VB can converted to C#, all of them make use of the same framework but vb has inherited some old functions from the vb6 that can be converted to c# look at my answer to that question [Using LSET or RSET in a c#-aspx application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677063/using-lset-or-rset-in-a-c-aspx-application/17677372#17677372), what I have done in that is that I used ILSpy and opened Microsoft.VisualBasic dll and looked at the Strings class implementation the ILSpy allow you to view the code in vb or in C#

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this url

[developerfusion.com/tools/](http://developerfusion.com/tools/)

This site provides conversion from C# to Vb.Net even you can also convert into Ruby and Python too using this.